# CSS Loading animation not animating in NW.js (node-webkit)

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, node-webkit, nw.js

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p183s9m/) with my CSS loading animation working properly.

However, when I use the same code in my node-webkit app, the SVG path and colors are static and show no animation.

After a bit of research, I tried adding

```
"chromium-args": "--enable-threaded-compositing"
```

to my package.json file as per the solution to [this issue](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1093). Unfortunately, this did not solve my issue.

I'm using a CSS animation for my loading screen as per advice from the second answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003130/angularjs-show-loading-animation-for-slow-script-e-g-while-filtering).

My animation is a slightly altered version of [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/joeyclouvel/full/gxKJp/).

Has anyone had similar issues with CSS animations in NW.js? Any reason why this animation might not be working?

I previously had just a simple spinning CSS animation in place and it worked fine in my NW.js app. I'm confused by this inconsistency.

Comment: It couldn't be something as simple as the lack of a need to load because you're working locally, could it?

Comment: @kthornbloom thanks for the thought but it still takes about 4 seconds for the content to load so the image just appears static for 4 seconds. And a previous loading animation that was just a spinning image worked fine.

Comment: experiencing this exact issue as well. i have an angular JS application with fadein-out animations for the views to stop the glitchiness of ng-route. works great in chrome, refuses to work in node-webkit (or nw.js as they go by now)

Comment: I have similar issues. Some of my animations work partially in NW, but work great in Chrome and Chromium. Do you guys know some way to copy the config-keys/switches/chrome://flags from Chromium to NW? I think this might help, but i don't know an automated way to do it.

Comment: @DarkoRiđić and JL Griffin I received an email today saying the issue I opened has been corrected and closed: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/2291

Comment: @user95227 thanks for notifiyng us :)

Answer (score 2):

**CSS webkit and SVG do not play well together.**

This is specifically only the CSS that uses animation/transform/@keyframe references:

`(-moz-webkit, -ms-webkit, -o-webkit, -webkit)`

If you notice in your fiddle, the CSS shows:

```
.activity-box img {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
/* Below is the key for the rotating animation */
-webkit-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
-moz-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
-o-animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
```

Wouldn't it be nice if you could use `.activity-box svg` instead of `.activity-box img`?

Unfortunately this doesnt work, per the `svg` is rendered in the browser, not with CSS webkit transforms.

```
<div id="flask">
<div class="background"></div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 113 130" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path fill="#E6E9EA" d="M0,0v130h112.084L111.75,0H0z M94.75,128C71,128,56,128,56,128s-14.873,0-38.623,0s-13.945-19.422-6.33-35.945S40,41.25,40,41.25V3h16h11v38.25c0,0,23.901,34.283,31.517,50.805S118.5,128,94.75,128z"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M56,127.5c0,0-14.873,0-38.623,0s-13.695-19.172-6.08-35.695C18.912,75.283,40.5,41.25,40.5,41.25V2.5h-9H56h19.5h-8v38.75c0,0,23.651,34.033,31.267,50.555c7.615,16.523,19.733,35.695-4.017,35.695S56,127.5,56,127.5z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
...
</div>
```

I would recommend either:

a) convert the animation to <s>`.gif`</s> `.png` or `.jpg` and not use `svg` 
(edit: `.gif` does not transform either, you can use the `.png` filetype instead, then create an `img.src` swapping function for each animation frame using javascript)

b) Remove CSS webkit animations and rework your `svg` to animate on its own, using `svg` animations. see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform

Comment: updated solution A for clarity. (both methods do have working implementations, FYI)